# texdoc can't find pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, texdoc

While I have the indispensable `pgfmanual.pdf` located in `/usr/share/doc/texmf/pgf/`,

```
texmf/pgf$ pwd
/usr/share/doc/texmf/pgf
texmf/pgf$ ls
pgfmanual.pdf
texmf/pgf$
```

texdoc cannot find it.

```
~$ texdoc -l pgf
 1 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-soroban/pgf-soroban-doc.pdf
   = Package documentation
 2 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-umlsd/pgf-umlsd-demo.pdf
   = Package demo
 3 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-umlsd/pgf-umlsd-demo2.pdf
   = Package demo (2)
 4 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-blur/pgf-blur.pdf
 5 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-soroban/README
   = Readme
 6 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-blur/README
   = Readme
 7 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-umlsd/README
Please enter the number of the file to view, anything else to skip: 
~$ texdoc -l tikz
 21 results.  Display them all? (y/N) y
 1 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-3dplot/tikz-3dplot_documentation.pdf
   = Package documentation
 2 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf
   = Package documentation
 3 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-dependency/tikz-dependency-doc.pdf
   = Package documentation
 4 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-inet/tikz-inet-doc.pdf
   = Package documentation
 5 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-qtree/tikz-qtree-manual.pdf
   = Package documentation
 6 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-timing/tikz-timing.pdf
   = Package documentation
 7 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/sa-tikz/sa-tikz-doc.pdf
 8 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/hf-tikz/hf-tikz.pdf
 9 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-timing/README
   = Readme
10 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-cd/README
   = Readme
11 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-3dplot/README
   = Readme
12 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-inet/README
   = Readme
13 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-qtree/README
   = Readme
14 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/hf-tikz/README.txt
15 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-dependency/README
16 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/sa-tikz/README
17 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/hf-tikz/README
18 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-bayesnet/README.rst
19 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-dependency/AUTHORS
20 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-3dplot/CHANGELOG
21 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-dependency/VERSION
Please enter the number of the file to view, anything else to skip:
```

EDIT per comment:

```
~$ kpathsea
zsh: command not found: kpathsea
~$ kpsewhich --var-value TEXMF
{/home/mrkelly/.texmf-config,/home/mrkelly/.texmf-var,/home/mrkelly/texmf,!!/etc/texmf,!!/var/lib/texmf,!!/usr/local/share/texmf,!!/usr/share/texmf,!!/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist}
```

The whole texlive distribution has been installed through `apt-get`.
The one exception here is the `pgfmanual.pdf` proper, which I un-archived because `texdoc` was having trouble reading archived manuals. That said, until I updated to saucy, `texdoc pgf` worked just fine.

How do I point texdoc in the right direction?

Comment: Is `/usr/share/doc/texmf/` really on your `kpathsea` radar? How is TeX Live installed?  What does `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMF` return?  (Note, in the directory you mention, I have a .gz version of the manual: `pgfmanual.pdf.gz`...)

Comment: `kpathsea` is not a command (try `texdoc kpathsea`); but, anyway, it is not searching in the directory you suppose it would.  A quick solution would be to do: `mkdir ~/texmf/doc/pgf` and put it in there.  But note that that directory will almost certainly be searched first, which means any subsequent system install of the same file won't be found first -- which is a problem if the subsequent file is newer!

Comment: I can not reproduce this with a vanilla TL2013 installation. _Upgrade_.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by an outdated installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the Debian/Ubuntu package. The Debian TeX policy clearly mandates that documentation (or a symlink to it) should be put in a place searched by texdoc, which is not done here. You should report that bug in the Debian and/or Ubuntu bug tracking system.

While waiting for the bug to be fixed, doing a symlink in a place searched by texdoc is a good workaround indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Per @jon's input, there is a simple workaround to this problem.

`ln -s /usr/share/doc/texmf/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf ~/texmf/doc/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf`

`texdoc pgf` will now work as intended.

Comment: I'm curious: do you mean `~/texmf` or `~/texdoc`?

Comment: As there are a few other packages with the same problem, I would recommend `ln -s /usr/share/doc/texmf ~/texmf/doc`